# Why does Git Extensions open a repository on startup? How to change the default repository on start up?

Tags: git-extensions

I recently changed my programming workspace on my computer. I created a directory C:\programming which contains everything programming related, tools, compilers, libs, codebases, etc.

I wanted a default structure that I can use everywhere I want, so I thought, why not create a git repository of my programming workspace, which I can check out on any new device I want to program on?!

So I did that.

A few days later I started wondering why Git Extensions always opened C:\programming as repository every time I started it.

I tried removing C:\programming from the latest repository list, deleting all the config files, searching in the registry for entries... All without success.

How do I change Git Extensions to not always open C:\programming as repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you don't want a default repository to open, change the program execution location to a location that does not have a .git repository in the folder or any parent folder. If you want a default location, change the program execution location to the folder with the repository.**

How did I find it out?

I first tried out [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer) to see if I can find any open file handles to config files I didn't find yet.

No success.

Then I recorded a process startup with [Process Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor). Yay 450.000 events! First I filtered for everything starting with "C:\programming" Thousands of entries. Then I remembered I should only look for File events with "C:\programming\.git", because a repository is opened. I saved a few of the first events, and went back unfiltered.

That's where I noticed [this peculiar pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1w6y.png).

It looks for \.git and \info, first in the program root directory, then one above that. "NAME NOT FOUND". Then it goes into "C:\programming" and voilá "SUCCESS". So it looks for .git repositories all the way up the file system hierarchy.

The fix was easy after this. I opened up my shortcut for Git Extensions and [changed the program execution location to C:\](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GO6ef.png).

No repository can be found in C:\, and there is no parent directory.

As a corollary, just change the execution location to any .git repository you want, and it will be the default one opened when you start Git Extensions.

Answer (score 5):

GitExtension open by default latest open repository.

You can disable this behavior here:

Tools > Settings > Git Extensions > Git Extensions > Open last working directory on startup

Comment: This is not relevant here. The option you mentioned was already off.

Comment: Than it shouldn't do that, unless you start GitExtensions with path to repository in command line.

Comment: Did you read my answer? One doesn't need to start it with path to repository, only ANY subdirectory of a repository. GitExtensions will keep looking up the directory tree for any repository it finds. This was exactly what I described in my answer.

Comment: I read only your question, it doesn't mention you install it in non standard folder.